# Possibility to have GET and POST in the curl configuration file

Tags: linux, rest, shell, curl

I have a shell script that calls the command: curl -K config_file.cfg.

However, the GET uses the bodysuit and this leads to an error

config_file.cfg :

```
#URL du WS 
#Definition des header
header="Content-Type:application/json"
header="Authorization:Basic UFNTOlNTTyNQU1M="

url=http://bonjour:15555/rappels/00077778

output=/data/exploit/tmp/liste_00077778.txt


url=http://bonjour:15555/rappels/add

output=/data/exploit/tmp/add_16011401.txt

data=@/home/IAB_TEST/query_post_body/add_16011401.json
```

```
curl -K config_file.cfg
```

```
{"timestamp":1561631007821,"status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException","message":"Request method 'POST' not supported","path":"/rappels/00077778"}
```

Comment: You can't post a file using GET

Comment: What does "bodysuit" mean?

Comment: I know I can't post a file using GET, I only want to use a POST query and a GET query inside the same config file

Comment: bodysuit = body/core of the POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert `--next` between the requests, this flag resets all local params.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `request` option in the config file to specify the request method.

```
#URL du WS 
#Definition des header
header="Content-Type:application/json"
header="Authorization:Basic UFNTOlNTTyNQU1M="

url=http://bonjour:15555/rappels/00077778
request=get
output=/data/exploit/tmp/liste_00077778.txt

url=http://bonjour:15555/rappels/add
request=post
output=/data/exploit/tmp/add_16011401.txt

data=@/home/IAB_TEST/query_post_body/add_16011401.json
```

Comment: It didn't work because the POST query use this parameter

Comment: I think you should be able to put it multiple times, to get a different method for each URL.

Comment: Warning: ws_calls.cfg:20: warning: 'post' is ambiguous

Comment: Try using `request=get` and `request=post`.

Comment: method 'POST' not supported again

Comment: I'm not sure you can specify multiple requests with different options in one config file.

Comment: I think the same :/

Comment: if it's a POST api call, it's going to have a request body, right? where do I put that?

Comment: @NikhilVJ It's in `data=body`.